# Are there any standalone compact keyboard / monitors?

Tags: display

Is there any dummy laptop which is basically just a display and keyboard/trackpad that has VGA input and USB input?

You could plug this unit's power in and USB keyboard in to a headless server to administer it.  Maybe it could fold up just like a regular keyboard and move it around?

I want to Google for it but I don't know what it is called.

Comment: Similar to: http://serverfault.com/questions/17981/using-a-laptop-as-an-external-monitor-and-keyboard-for-a-server

Comment: You might find this link useful: http://community.spiceworks.com/topic/89421-i-am-looking-for-a-cart-for-my-server-room

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are generally called [rackmount screen and keyboard KVMs (Google search)](http://www.google.com/search?q=server%20console&rls=com.microsoft:en-us&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&startIndex=&startPage=1#pq=server%20console&hl=en&sugexp=kjrmc&cp=30&gs_id=2h&xhr=t&q=server%20screen%20and%20keyboard%20kvm&qe=c2VydmVyIHNjcmVlbiBhbmQga2V5Ym9hcmQga3Zt&qesig=aHeWB0ROCCofLWr3ETb3wg&pkc=AFgZ2tmmqQ9Tm_sB_tztqVPgGtZYLq0a-LNGB52NPqXokMHvhzrFajyGAi99QGd2xk5Dx2fOejh_hbIa9FoooO6HaIodlvR93g&pf=p&sclient=psy-ab&rls=com.microsoft:en-us&biw=1181&bih=661&source=hp&pbx=1&oq=server%20screen%20and%20keyboard%20kvm&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=&gs_upl=&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.,cf.osb&fp=d566e0fbd09c8604) for use in server closets.

The KVM function allows them to connect to multiple systems and use the included keyboard and mouse to control the systems. They also usually have a pointing device such as a touchpad or trackball for mouse control.

They may also be called "server consoles" because the console is the portion of the system you interact with, eg. the keyboard and the mouse and the screen.